# Outlook API 1.3 version not showing on Outlook Desktop Professional Plus 2016

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

On this page https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets.md it is specified that both Outlook 2016 (MSI) for Windows and Outlook 2013 for Windows support Outlook API up to Version 1.4, but when we try to increase the minimal version in the manifest from 1.1 to 1.3, the addin works fine on web but does not show on both desktop versions.

Currently I am working on Outlook Professional Plus 2016 with build number 16.0.4312.100, 64bit on Windows 10.

I am trying a simple addin generated by yeoman office-generator, with only change is the minimal version from 1.1 to 1.3

Thanks.

**Update**

The provided build number was wrong, the build number is 16.0.4312.1000.
Here is a screenshot from where i got the build number https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ8eK.jpg

Comment: Could you share the manifest you're trying to install? How do you look for your build number of Outlook?

Comment: The provided build number was wrong, i updated the post.
Here is the manifest https://pastebin.com/pqRYpk3h

Comment: We tested this on the latest version of Outlook - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018296/march-6-2018-update-for-outlook-2016-kb4018296, and the manifest worked no matter if the apiset was 1.1 or 1.3. We noticed that the icon in your manifest is pointing to localhost, if there is not actually an icon there it can take a while for Outlook to "detect" before it shows up with the default icon. Can you try replacing your icon links to actual images? Can you also try upgrading Outlook to latest?(though I do not believe there were any fixes between the two versions that would affect this)

Comment: Just to make sure you are modifying this value right? <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3"> (the pastebin you provided was the manifest that is NOT working for you?)

Comment: We can confirm that the manifest in the pastebin works on another newer outlook 2016 for business, with both 1.1 and 1.3. The problem seems to be with our outlook professional plus 2016 which came pre-installed with windows 10 on our laptop.

Comment: Yeah that version probably needs to be updated to get all the latest fixes. For this specific issue, you may need to also take into some Offic e updates in addition to the Outlook update. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011686/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoffice2016february13-2018) and https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/3191923/september-5-2017-update-for-office-2016-kb3191923 I will investigate to see if there is an all up containing update that will bring all binaries up to date.

Comment: The latest version of all office binaries are here: https://support.office.com/article/72c7615f-5e88-4eec-b492-147e99d79997

There is no one link to update all the binaries. but Windows Update should automatically install all the updates for you. You can use the above link to verify that the version of dlls are at the latest versions. The relevant ones for this feature would be outlook.exe, osf.dll, osfshared.dll. To be safe the dlls with MSO* should be updated as well.