# Office addin not shown in Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We have an Office Addin in the [Appsource marketplace](https://appsource.microsoft.com/de/product/office/WA104381095?tab=Overview).
Currently there is a customer that reports the addin is not visible on certain Outlook for Windows installations and I'm not sure if it is related to 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235073/outlook-api-1-3-version-not-showing-on-outlook-desktop-professional-plus-2016) as there are different versions.

- The addin is correctly installed and visible in the Web.
- The computer and Outlook has been restarted multiple times to avoid any sync issues

---

Within the same company, it is working on:

- Outlook for Windows 2013 (15.0.5085.1000) 64 bit
- Outlook for Windows 2016 MSO (16.0.4738.1000) 64 bit

---

It is **NOT** working on:

- Outlook for Windows 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 64 bit
- Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.19029.20045) 32bit

---

Are there any known limitations? Is there a list of Outlook versions that do not work even appsource say they are supported?

PS: Outlook Prod team told me to raise the questions here with the tag.

Comment: It is only your add-in, or any add-in?  Do you have COM-style add-ins installed? 
 We have seen the new Outlook Apps not appear at all in some cases when there are COM-style add-ins already installed.  You have to disable the COM-style add-ins one at a time (or all of them) to see when the new Outlook Apps appear.  Its not that they are incompatible in principle, but some COM add-ins seem to block Outlook Apps from being shown.

Comment: Are you sure 19029 is the correct version number? It seems too high to be one. (but it may be a build I'm not aware of). In any case if your API set in your manifest is high, then it could be possible that older versions of Outlook do not support that API Set. (as 4266 is older than 4738)

Comment: Do other Web add-ins that you install from the store also not show up on those clients?